# Within group move date to same date in prior year

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':['cust1', 'cust1', 'cust1', 'cust2', 'cust2', 'cust3', 'cust3', 'cust3'],
              'date':[date(2017, 12, 15), date(2018, 12, 20), date(2020, 1, 10), date(2017, 12, 15), date(2018, 12, 10), date(2017, 1, 5), date(2018, 1, 15), date(2019, 2, 20)],
              'c':[5, 6, 7, 4, 8, 6, 5, 9]})

       a        date  c
0  cust1  2017-12-15  5
1  cust1  2018-12-20  6
2  cust1  2020-01-10  7
3  cust2  2017-12-15  4
4  cust2  2018-12-10  8
5  cust3  2017-01-05  6
6  cust3  2018-01-15  5
7  cust3  2019-02-20  9
```

'a' = customer

'date' = date when customer paid

'c' = amount customer paid

I need to check if the customer paid in each year but for customers which historically paid in December but in later years paid in January I would like to change the January date to a December date. so looking at cust1, historically she paid in December but then she missed to pay in December 2019 but paid in January 2020. I would like to move the date to the same day in December in the prior year.

Note: my dataframe has thousands with more customers and pay dates all through the year but i specifically want to apply the above rule only where historically payments were made in December but in later years are being made in January.

my resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
       a        date  c
0  cust1  2017-12-15  5
1  cust1  2018-12-20  6
2  cust1  2019-12-10  7
3  cust2  2017-12-15  4
4  cust2  2018-12-10  8
5  cust3  2017-01-05  6
6  cust3  2018-01-15  5
7  cust3  2019-02-20  9
```

**EDIT**

my dataframe is slightly more complex then initially described above, complexity being that I can have several times a customer is making a payment during any one year

```
        a        date  c
0   cust1  2017-06-15  5
1   cust1  2017-12-15  5
2   cust1  2018-06-15  6
3   cust1  2019-01-20  6
4   cust1  2019-06-15  7
5   cust1  2020-01-10  7
6   cust1  2020-06-12  8
7   cust2  2017-12-15  4
8   cust2  2018-12-10  8
9   cust3  2017-01-05  6
10  cust3  2018-01-15  5
11  cust3  2019-02-20  9
```

so looking at cust1 she always makes 2 payments during the year. but the December 2018 payment was only done in January 2019. I would like to adjust the January date to a December date if in the prior year the payment was made in December and the for any subsequent years were there is a January payment

so my resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
        a       date  c    newDate
0   cust1 2017-06-15  5 2017-06-15
1   cust1 2017-12-15  5 2017-12-15
2   cust1 2018-06-15  6 2018-06-15
3   cust1 2019-01-20  6 2018-12-20
4   cust1 2019-06-15  7 2019-06-15
5   cust1 2020-01-10  7 2019-12-10
6   cust1 2020-06-12  8 2020-06-12
7   cust2 2017-12-15  4 2017-12-15
8   cust2 2018-12-10  8 2018-12-10
9   cust3 2017-01-05  6 2017-01-05
10  cust3 2018-01-15  5 2018-01-15
11  cust3 2019-02-20  9 2019-02-20
```

I tried the following incorporating some of the suggestions below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['cust1', 'cust1', 'cust1', 'cust1', 'cust1', 'cust1', 'cust1', 'cust2', 'cust2', 'cust3', 'cust3', 'cust3'],
                   'date':[date(2017, 6, 15), date(2017, 12, 15), date(2018, 6, 15), date(2019, 1, 20), date(2019, 6, 15), date(2020, 1, 10), date(2020, 6, 12), date(2017, 12, 15), date(2018, 12, 10), date(2017, 1, 5), date(2018, 1, 15), date(2019, 2, 20)],
                   'c':[5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 4, 8, 6, 5, 9]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')
df_2 = df.loc[df['date'].dt.month.isin(year_end_month)].copy()
df_3 = pd.concat([df, df_2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
s=df_2.groupby('a').date.shift().dt.month
df_2['newDate']=np.where(s.eq(12) & df_2.date.dt.month.eq(1), df_2.date- 
pd.DateOffset(months=1), df_2.date)
df_4 = pd.concat([df_2, df_3])
df_4.newDate = df_4.newDate.fillna(df_4.date)
df_4.sort_values(by=['a', 'date'])
```

The problem with my the above approach is that it works the first time the payment date is moved from December to January but it doesn't work for subsequent years. so looking at cust1 first time she switchted payment from December to January was in December 2018 to January 2019 and my approach captures this. but my approach fails to move her 2019 payment which she made in January 2020 to December 2019. Any idea how this can be solved for?

Answer (score 1):

Check with `groupby` `shift` and find the row have the need to be fix , then do `np.where`

```
s=df.groupby('a').date.shift().dt.month
df['date']=np.where(s.eq(12) & df.date.dt.month.eq(1), df.date-pd.DateOffset(months=1), df.date)
df
       a       date  c
0  cust1 2017-12-15  5
1  cust1 2018-12-20  6
2  cust1 2019-12-10  7
3  cust2 2017-12-15  4
4  cust2 2018-12-10  8
5  cust3 2017-01-05  6
6  cust3 2018-01-15  5
7  cust3 2019-02-20  9
```

Comment: thanks your solution works for my initial problem. however, my dataframe is slightly more complex the initially described. any idea how above can be solved?